# How to make 3gp from audio and image in Android?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, 3gp

I have problem at make 3gp video from audio and image.

is there any simple way to make video fro audio and one image? or can you provide some example of it?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, how did you manage to achieve this feature? Can you please share the steps that you followed? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean programatically - if so, depending on how you define 'simple'(!), you could use ffmpeg.

There are a number of ffmpeg wrapper for Android projects that you can either use or look at to design your own. Some examples:

- http://hiteshsondhi88.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/
- https://github.com/jhotovy/android-ffmpeg

ffmpeg syntax evolves over time but the link below should be a good starting point for the syntax you need:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6087453/334402